# Tirth-Yantra Parva

Tags: mahabharata, sanskrit

So on Wikipedia the Vana Parva has this Ajagara Parva on Yudishtir and the snake, yet in this digitized version of the Mahabharata it is in the Tirtha-Yantra Parva. Here is the link: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7458.html my question is one is this translated correctly from Sanskrit and two why the difference?